# AWS EC2 Public IP based in Sydney

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I tried changing the location to Asia/Pacific(Sydney) and created an instance with default configuration and my instance is assigned to a US-based IP address.

I created another VPC with subnet using AWS IP range with Sydney-based list and then created an instance, my private IP is assigned to Sydney-based IP address but still my public IP address is assigned to some US-based IP address.

Is there any way I can get a Sydney-based IP address to my instance?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating an EIP in the Sydney region and attaching it to the instance then checking again? No guarantee that'll work, but your chances will certainly be better than getting a randomly assigned one.

How did you determine the IP was US based? I imagine that sometimes the IP blocks move around from region to region as demand shifts.. It might be possible to get an EIP stuck in the Sydney region. You could also probably script something out to do the following:

1. Create an EIP
2. Geo-locate it

   2a. If it's not Sydney/Australia, destroy EIP ==> return to step 1
3. If the geo-locate resolves to Sydney/Aus, stop the script.

Good luck :)